# How to disable html5mode on otherwise?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, ngroute

I want to switch off `$locationProvider.html5Mode()` when the path goes out of my routes. (a.k.a. /pages).

The `otherwise` route currently consumes my links to other pages and only updates the `ng-view` with a blank template, I want the whole page reloads to target page instead.

Here is my code.

```
app.config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/page/:url', {
    controller: 'PageCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'page-template.html'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: function(params, path) {
      window.location = path;
    }
  });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found a work around to this, by adding all "reloading" links with a `target="_self"`.

Below is a portion of [**RTFM**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location).

### Html link rewriting

In cases like the following, links are not rewritten; instead, the browser will perform a full page reload to the original link.

- Links that contain target element
  Example: `<a href="/ext/link?a=b" target="_self">link</a>`
- Absolute links that go to a different domain
  Example: `<a href="http://angularjs.org/">link</a>`
- Links starting with '/' that lead to a different base path
  Example: `<a href="/not-my-base/link/">link</a>`